# How to release on GitHub through the command line and to attach a large file?

Tags: github

Is it possible to release on GitHub **through the command** line with an attached file that is not pushed to a repository?

I have a file over 1GB that I easily attached through a web GitHub release page, but I want to automate that using bash.

Comment: Are you asking how to attach release assets to a release using the API?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can from command-line, using `gh`: [`cli/cli/`](https://github.com/cli/cli/)

- [create a relase](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create)

  ```
    gh release create <tag> [<files>...] [flags]
  ```
- [upload a file to that release](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_upload)

  ```
    gh release upload <tag> <files>... [flags]
  ```

And since [Github CLI 2.4.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.4.0) (Dec. 2021), you have:

- the non-interactive flag `--generate-notes`, which allows you to skip the editor phase.
- an interactive mode to choose a tag name

Comment: Thanks, `gh release create` works perfectly and uploading my file.

Answer (score 1):

There's [a REST API that can be used for this purpose](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#upload-a-release-asset).  It's used to upload a release asset if you know the ID for the release (which you can get by querying the release itself).  You can also get the upload URL by querying the release using a `GET` request; that returns the `upload_url` attribute.

If you want an example of how to do this from the command line with curl, Git LFS has [a script that it uses to do releases and upload assets](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/19e217f6bc8ce0a14f19e3f6a43c8d7c6f54f426/script/upload) which you could look at.  It's a little complex, but it is reasonably comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [`gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli) tool and directly using the REST API (as mentioned in other answers), there are several command-line tools which let you create and manipulate GitHub releases. These are likely to be much simpler to use than directly using the REST API.

There is only one* I could identify that I could unreservedly recommend, however: [github-release](https://github.com/github-release/github-release), which is written in Go. Binaries can be downloaded from the project's [Releases](https://github.com/github-release/github-release/releases) page, it "[dogfoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) (transparently uses its own tool), and is actively maintained (as at January 2022).

Some others are:

- Another Go app called [github-release](https://github.com/buildkite/github-release), released by [BuildKite](https://buildkite.com). However, this seems to be less actively maintained, and it doesn't transparently "dogfood" (viewing its CI results require an account with BuildKite).
- For Haskell developers, there's yet *another* tool called [`github-release`](https://github.com/tfausak/github-release), created by [Taylor Fausak](https://github.com/tfausak). It seems to be actively maintained; however, no downloadable executables are provided, so you must build it yourself using a Haskell compiler and build tools.
- For node.js developers, there's [release-it](https://github.com/release-it/release-it); but as a node project, it doesn't provide executable binaries that could be invoked from Bash at all.

*If there are others that I've missed, feel free to add them in comments.

Comment: In addition to the apps mentioned above, various snippets of code show how to create and manipulate GitHub releases in other languages. e.g. this Python Gist https://gist.github.com/tomac4t/16dc1e91d95c94f60251e586672b6314, and these in Bash: https://gist.github.com/stefanbuck/ce788fee19ab6eb0b4447a85fc99f447, https://gist.github.com/schell/2fe896953b6728cc3c5d8d5f9f3a17a3